# Allowing CORS from React front end not allowing Express back end to use Bing API

Tags: reactjs, express, cors

I currently have my front end and back end separate. When I start my React app on `localhost:3000` to hit my Express app at `localhost:8000/search/results?search_query=`, I get blocked by CORS. So I set this in my Express backend's `app.js` file:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/search', search);
app.use('/results', result);

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port 8000...')
})
```

I am calling my back end route from my front end using this function in React:

```
 bingSearch(term) {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/search/results?search_query=' + term)
    .then((response) => {
      response.json()
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({results: json})
      })
    })
  }
```

I don't get the CORS error after that. However, the route I'm hitting is a route that uses the Bing Web Search API which has a subscription key that I pass in through the header for that GET request. My app, however, just hangs now.

How and where should I be allowing the CORS that will allow my front end to connect to my back end but will not be disrupting my Bing API GET request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call next() in your middleware.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

You can read more about it here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use cors-proxy-server for this. However, it is only good for testing purposes. For production, you need to have server side calls to Bing API. More information is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/bing-web-search-resource-faq.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't quite clear. My Bing API fetching is being done entirely in the back end. That's what is being used when the `search/results` route is being hit in Express. That's what your'e referring to when you say to have it be server side calls?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having issue with allowed headers with cors, if I am correct, could you try add this with Express:

```
res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, BING_API_HEADER'
  );
```

So in front end, you will need to `set` header using the same name as `BING_API_HEADER`. This will allow you to access the header info from your server. Once you get the header, you can use it to make API calls.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the function from my React front end that is sending the request to my back end route. When I set the header in my fetch app, what would be the key value pair? `BING_API_HEADER : ?` Would I be adding my subscription key there also the way I set it in my back end?

Comment: Where is the header you are talking about? You said you are sending the API key in the header?

Comment: I dont really get how the communication between FE and BE would affect your server api call with bing. All you need to do is to pass whatever you need from FE to BE, and then use those information to call the BING API

Comment: That's what I'm not getting either. My back end works fine with the API when I use Postman. Using the front end then causes CORS errors. Adding the code to my back end to allow CORS then stops my Bing API function to not work. No idea why.

As far as the API key goes, I am sending that through a header in my `bingSearch` function using `axios`. But that's all back end. I'm not sure why my React front end affects that at all.

Comment: Postman takes care the CORS issue for you, that's why you are not running that issue. Could you explain to me the work flow? So the user on the FE does something to trigger the your server BE to do a API request with Bing. Is there anything coming from FE? Does FE needs to send anything to the server? Or it is a simple get request to tell server to go fetch something.

Comment: looks like you figured it out! :)